How to save coreldraw file in 11.0 version using 23.0(2021) version?
I am using coreldraw 2021(23.0) version. My client uses corel 11 version. But in save as option, lowest I see is 15.0. Is there any way to save file in 11.0 version?

Corel Draw 11 is over 20 years old, and version 15 is nearly 15 years old. If you save in version 15, can the client open the file? Is it entirely broken, or just parts of it incorrect? Do you need full interoperability with the file format, or can you save to an independent file type that both clients support?

If you are attempting to transfer a file that can still be worked on with the full capabilities of Corel Draw in both the versions, the answer is "no". If you just want to save it in Corel Draw version 11 format, that answer is "no" for the same reason. Corel Draw version 23 cannot save in the Corel Draw version 11 file format.
If you are just trying to get an image file transferred to this client and they don't really need to be able to perform further work on it, the answer would be to export the file to a compatible independent image format.
Corel Draw version 11 is more than 20 years old. Version 15 is nearly 15 years old and it is impressive they still support that as a backwards compatible target version.

I just want to save file as 11.0 version. No more changings are required in file. Is there a way to do so. Kindly help.

I already answered that question, but I added a few lines to my answer to make it more clear. The answer is "no". I assumed that the reason you'd want to save to that specific file type is to allow additional editing/work on the file. Even if you're not trying to do that the answer is the same.

Alright! Thanks for your assistance.

If this answers your question, use the Checkmark icon to the left of my answer to mark it as such, to indicate the question has been answered. This is not permanent. If someone else provides a better answer later, you are free to remove the mark on this answer and add it to the other.
